# Use socket to comunicate between process in the same host, is it ok go with UDP?

Tags: sockets, udp, ipc

I want to make sure, if use UDP within a host, should i care about the package lost issue?

Comment: Pipes are a better option for 1:1 stream comms between processes on the same host.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should care about reliability when using UDP. Even if you use it on localhost, there is no guaranty that packets are not lost because the Protocol Specifications does not ensure this. It also depends on the implementation of UDP in Operating System. It may behave differently on different operating systems as far as reliability is concerned because there is no rule defined in UDP specifications.

Also the order of delivery in UDP is not ensured so you should also take care of it while using UDP for IPC.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Also the number of deliveries per datagram is not guaranteed. Anything from zero upwards.

Comment: Thanks very much Tayyab and EJP, got it